# Fetching unmacted data from 2 Mysql tables having huge data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables, table A (80,00,000 records) and table B (20,00,000 records), which share a common column, `mobile_no` and it's data type is `BIGINT(20)`. I want to compare them and fetch the unmatched records.

I have the following solution, which works only for small datasets:

```
 SELECT mobile_no FROM A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT mobile_no 
 FROM B where A.mobile_no = B.mobile_no).
```

> Note: I have applied indexing on column mobile_no in both tables.

When I ran the above query, execution was stopped after the default time (10 min). We increased the time as well, but still it is not getting the output for huge data.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone give me a solution for this problem.

Comment: FYI - apparently a lakh is equivalent to 100,000.

Comment: IMHO there is nothing you can do better. The LEFT JOIN query should be equivalent performancewise. You should check if your indexes fit into memory.

Comment: This might be of interest, but little help - https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Try to increase the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)

Answer (score 2):

Just try this and let us know if it works for the specified huge datasets..

```
SELECT A.mobile_no
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.mobile_no = B.mobile_no and B IS NULL
```

And if it still doesn't give you the result in reasonable time frame... then try creating indexes on the two tables you are dealing with.

You can go through this link [Indexes and Fine tuning](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) to get an idea on how to fine tune your queries to make it work faster.

Comment: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query execution after 461.469 sec. i have already added indexing on mobile_no column.

Comment: not just mobile_no column..but all the columns that you are fetching in the select statement need to be indexed if possible i.e. if they are eligible for indexing.   Other than indexing may be you can use an sql job to run this query so that it wont stop in the middle with timeout exception. But I am not sure if MySQL has features like sql jobs and execution plan. I predominantly work on sql server which makes my life a lot simpler.

Comment: sure i'll try and let you know the status, Thanks.